# Appending values to a column in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have various files containing data. I want to extract one specific column from each file and create a new dataframe with one column containing all the extracted data.

So for example I have 3 files:

```
A B C
1 2 3 
4 5 6

A B C
7 8 9
8 7 6

A B C
5 4 3
2 1 0
```

The new dataframe should only contain the values from column C:

```
C
3
6
9
6
3
0
```

So the column of the first file should be copied to the new dataframe, the column from the second file should be appendend to the new dataframe.

My code looks like this so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('*.dat'):

df= pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter="\t", header=6)
df1= df["Bias"]

print(df)
```

Now df1 is overwritten in each loop step. Would it be a good idea to create a temporary dataframe in each loop step and then copy the data to the new dataframe?

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list comprehension` or `for` loop with `append` for `list of DataFrame`s and if need only some columns add parameter `usecols`, last [`concat`](http://pands.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all together for big `DataFrame`:

```
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, delimiter="\t", header=6, usecols=['C']) for f in glob.glob('*.dat')]
```

Or:

```
dfs = []
for filename in glob.glob('*.dat'):
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter="\t", header=6, usecols=['C'])
    #if need all columns 
    #df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter="\t", header=6)
    dfs.append(df)
```

---

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```